# Why is there a delay before accepting a click after text input?

Tags: dart

I modified the Dart To Do example on DartPad to create an Add button. However if you type something in on desktop Chrome or Firefox and then quickly click Add, it doesn't do anything after your first click. Typing something then waiting a second takes care of this and of course using "Enter" avoids it altogether. But does this have to do with the 300ms click delay? Can it be worked around? Dartpad code link below:

https://dartpad.dartlang.org/8df30796e79c3dd62e8e

Comment: I can't reproduce. When I hover the mouse over the button in order to be able to click fast and write something with the other hand, then immediately after stop writing click the "Add" button, the item is added without any recognizable delay. What OS are you using? (I'm on Linux).

Comment: I am on Windows 10 but also tried on Windows 7 and I am noticing it now with any form, not just Dart. Type anything and then quickly try to click a button and you have to click again. Just happened with this form as well! :)

Comment: Maybe some installed browser plugin?

Comment: Just a wild guess. Try `on-tap` instead of `on-click`.